# Invalid refresh token while trying to refresh an access token on Office365 APIs

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, office365

I'm currently trying to develop a web application which syncs calendars from Office365, and so far I managed to fetch a couple of tokens from Azure's OAuth system.

But, even though the Refresh token seems to have at least a validity period of 14days, it seems that whenever I try to refresh my Access Token, I always get the following error :

```
OAuth error: "AADSTS70000: Authentication failed. Refresh Token is not valid.
Trace ID: 47836649-e160-40f0-93d1-f599caf4f665
Correlation ID: 45714317-5a29-4242-a785-be23269acf19
Timestamp: 2015-03-09 09:53:18Z"
```

Any ideas ? Thanks

-- edit --

Here is the request made to refresh the token ;

```
//parameters
refresh_token={refresh_token}
&grant_type=refresh_token
&client_id={client_id}
&client_secret={client_secret}
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com

// url
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token
```

-- edit 2 --

Here is the exact json response I'm receiving ;

```json
{
    "error":"invalid_grant",
    "error_description":"AADSTS70000: Authentication failed. Refresh Token is not valid.\r\nTrace ID: f0b5bc67-9ad5-4a75-b384-393486b31074\r\nCorrelation ID: 05af63f5-989a-4397-924f-58745c9bc964\r\nTimestamp: 2015-03-09 12:21:08Z","error_codes":[70000],
    "timestamp":"2015-03-09 12:21:08Z",
    "trace_id":"f0b5bc67-9ad5-4a75-b384-393486b31074",
    "correlation_id":"05af63f5-989a-4397-924f-58745c9bc964",
    "submit_url":null,
    "context":null
}
```

As outlined in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx, it means that my refresh token is outdated... But I just generated it through the full authorization mechanism, that is what I can't understand !

Comment: check this : http://www.onlinecode.org/access-token-office-365-using-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution to my problem. Azure tokens are really huge (about 630 characters for the refresh token), and as we store the refresh token in a varchar(255), it is truncated, hence invalid...

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get access token 1st time you will be using an url which will return a response. In the response you will be getting a refresh token. You can use it to get access token again. But if you tried the same url which is used previously, you will be getting a new refresh token. You can not use the first refresh token anymore. You have to use the new refresh token.

I think you are using the previous refresh token.

Have a look on this link :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx

Comment: I just editer my question with some logs, and it happens the first time I'm making this request, so this can't be it, unless I oversaw a potential first request... I'll try to curl my way in to see if it is that, and then a problem on the lib I'm using

Comment: Tested to no avail ; so it can't be that I'm using a "previous refresh token" as I can't even refresh on the first time...

Comment: I added the json response in my original question ; so, according to your link, as I have a `invalid_grant`, it means that my refresh token is expired... but i just generated it through the full authorization request just 10 seconds before doing that request !

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you have a '?' at the beginning of your parameters. Are you passing those as part of the URL? Because they should be posted as form data in the body of the request, not as URL query parameters.

Comment: I added the `?` when dumping it here, so it is not there on the actual request. It seems that it is a GET request though ; the json I pasted there is on a POST request if that can help

Comment: Another thing to try: Azure can be very strict on resource URLs. Add a '/' to the end of your resource value (or %2F).

Comment: Nevermind, I think I found my problem. It seems that as I'm storing the refresh token in my database, we are using a varchar(255), while the refresh token seems to be more than 600 chars...